# ConfigureAwait(false) and events in library code

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

So I know that I should use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in library code in general. Exception is when I know that continuation will need caller context.
However, I don't know what should I do if I *do not know* it'll be the case. I am guessing that I should not use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in such case - however I'd like to confirm this.

Example: my class has few events:

```
public static event TriggeredWebhookInfo WebhookTriggered;
public static event ReadonlyWebhookInfo WebhookCancelled;
```

And there's a method (it's `private` as it's called by a `public Task` returning method, but it also uses `ConfigureAwait(false)`):

```
private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> TriggerTaskAsync(string url, WebhookBody body)
{
    if (body == null || url == null)
    {
        WebhookCancelled?.Invoke(url, body);
        Logger.Write(InternalTag.Sender, "Webhook cancelled: " + url, LogType.Normal);
        return null;
    }
    HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.PostAsync(url, GetContent(body)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    WebhookTriggered?.Invoke(url, body, response);
    Logger.Write(InternalTag.Sender, "Webhook triggered: " + url, LogType.Normal);
    return response;
}
```

Now, of course this works completely fine for any terminal application. However, what would happen if event invokes method on UI context assigned by user in a non-terminal application? Will `Invoke()` mitigate any issues, or should I remove `ConfigureAwait(false)` from the call stack to this method?

Comment: `when I know that continuation will need caller context.` that means, when *your continuation* needs to return to that context. Even if you know that the *caller* will want to return to its original context, let the *caller* decide. If in doubt, use `ConfigureAwait(false)`

Comment: The caller knows if they need the original context. In general, you shouldn't make assumptions about which thread(s) will invoke events and end up running your event handler code.

Comment: Event though reverse everything. They aren't expected to be asynchronous - they can't be. That's why `async void` is used instead of `async Task` in event handlers. The thread they run on should be documented - a thread owned by the control/threadpool/whatever or the UI thread? You'll find event documentation that says the event is raised on this or that event. If you want them to run on the UI thread you may have to go to extra lengths to find the UI synchronization context. Simply removing `ConfigureAwait(false)` won't do that, unless `TriggerTaskAsycn` was called from the UI thread itself

Comment: Having these events raised on different threads gives the client programmer a major migraine of course.  Extra painful because Canceled is raised on the calling thread but Triggered is not.  It is a pretty simple case here, just don't automatically use it.  Neither the event handler nor the Logger.Write() benefits from running on another thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make a design call - is the event guaranteed to return on the same context that called the public method or not? Base your decision on similar use cases, such as `WebClient`'s `DownloadDataCompleted`, an event that is raised when `DownloadDataAsync` is called. Once you've decided, *document that clearly* and ensure that you obey that specification.

Generally speaking, I would choose the option to *not* invoke the event on the original context. If the caller wants to marshal back, it can always do that. But if it doesn't need to, you're forcing your entire `async` chain to fight for the original contxt every time it returns from an async call, for nothing. Be context-free as much as you can, and marshal back at the last possible moment.

Of course, you can ask yourself if you need both an event and a Task-returning method that both signal the exact same async event. Is the client listening to the `WebHookTriggered` event the same code that calls the public async method?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to allow method handlers to have the same context as your caller, you would need to remove `ConfigureAwait(false)`. That said, you could do it either way; the important thing is to *document* what your consumers should expect.

Alternatively, you could use `IObservable<T>` for publishing your events, but that is much more complex and brings in another (non-trivial) dependency.

Comment: Removing `ConfigureAwait(false)` will work only if TriggerTaskAsync is called from the UI thread. Raising events on the UI thread in response to background processing, eg the way [BackgroundWorker does](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/compmod/system/componentmodel/BackgroundWorker.cs,157),  is a complex situation already and requires the use of AsyncOperation, AsyncOperationManager. Observable is probably simpler

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Oh, right. I recommend just documenting whether the context is kept or not, not whether the event is raised on a UI thread. From the op's description, this library may be used in situations where there *is* no UI thread.

Comment: This is correct - in fact I'd assume it's more likely to be used in terminal applications, and it was developed with such use case in mind. However, I can think of use cases where it'd be UI application - and I'd probably program one myself.